# HTML Tabs that slide when needed

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a situation where I want to display a number of tabs in a confined area.  I'm wondering if I can set it up so that I have arrows on either end and be able to click to bring the hidden tabs into view.  Or even grab the tab strip witht he move and move it back and forth as I need to

For example I may have 10 tabs but only room to view 5

Tab 1  Tab 2  Tab 3  Tab 4  Tab 5  Tab 6  Tab 7  Tab 8  Tab 9  Tab 10

Tabs 1-5 are visible, Tabs 6-10 hidden.  I want to be able to arrow across or drag across to make Tabs 6-10 visible.  When I do that Tabs 1-5 become hidden

Each click on the right (or left) arrow or each drag should move one tab

Comment: You're describing a carousel. Google by that keyword and there are countless libraries available.

Comment: i think you are expecting something like this http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/

Comment: Thanks Pandiyan Cool, that's exactly what I was after

Comment: I see no particular reason to tag this `jquery-ui`. Hence I removed it and added `html` which seems more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery Slider Tabs`

**Step 1: Including the files**

Unzip the package into your working directory and include them in your head section like this. Make sure you include jQuery before the plugin.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery.sliderTabs.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.sliderTabs.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

**Step 2: Markup**

First make a div element including first a list of links for tabs and the same number of div elements afterwards for panels. To link the div panels to the tabs, make sure that the href attribute of the tab links is '#IdOfPanel'. Note that list of tabs is required markup even if you plan on disabling tabs as other parts of the plugin like indicators depend on these declarations. Here's a basic example.

```
<div id="mySliderTabs">
  <!-- Unordered list representing the tabs -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#canyon">The Grand Canyon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#taj">The Taj Mahal</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bigben">Big Ben</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Afterwards, include the div panels representing the panels of our slider -->
  <div id="canyon">
    <h3>The Grand Canyon</h3>
    <!-- rest of the panel content -->
  </div>
  <div id="taj">
    <h3>The Taj Mahal</h3>
    <!-- rest of the panel content -->
  </div>
  <div id="bigben">
    <h3>Big Ben</h3>
    <!-- rest of the panel content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**Step 3: Invoking the plugin**

Then select the container div with jQuery and call sliderTabs() on it.

```
var slider = $("div#mySliderTabs").sliderTabs();
... or specify some options. View a full list of available options in the next section.

var slider = $("div#mySliderTabs").sliderTabs({
  autoplay: true,
  mousewheel: false,
  position: "bottom"
});
```

---

[`Reference`](http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/)

[`Download`](http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/sliderTabs-1.1.zip)